# Is there a lag time for pushing Clarity data to Google Analytics?

Tags: ms-clarity

## **Question:**

Is there a lag time between Clarity & Google Analytics?

## **Problem:**

Google Analytics doesn't appear to be receiving any data from Clarity.

## **Context:**

I created an application extender sppkg for an intranet that is pulling data into Clarity, which is great, but another requirement is to use Google Analytics (GA) along with it. So I integrated GA with Clarity, and verified that Clarity created a new dimension like the documentation described (*I did this manually as well as through the setup tool in case something weird was going on*) however, no data is making it's way to GA, and the GA dashboard in the Clarity tool says, "No data available".

## **Screenshots**

[screenshot of no data available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX0iC.png)

[screenshot of good GA connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsMy8.png)

Comment: I'm going to wait until tomorrow morning to re-test and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Waited a couple days, received the same result. Microsoft mentioned it could take 1-2 days to initially populate the data, but still hasn't populated yet.

Comment: @TylerH I just posted an answer for this, sorry it took a long time.

Answer (score 0):

## Long Answer :

There is no lag time, but I was not receiving any data on the GA (Google Analytics) panels is because you have to also push the data into GA and then the integration between Clarity & GA work together to populate the panels in Clarity.

## Short Answer :

Clarity has no methods for pulling & sending to GA.